# import or require js file in another js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm not sure if this has been answered before. I am trying to build a node express API, where I now need to include another js file so I can spread up my code.

Basically, I have a server.js file where I want to call a function in a router.js file. Is this possible?

Have tried using import, because i read that ES6 now supports that.
**Code:**

```
import routers from '/router.js';
```

Have also tried with the 'required' keyword, but that does not help either. The router.js file is also just placed in the root as the server.js.

**Package.json:**

```
 {
    "name": "nodeexpresapi",
    "main": "server.js",
    "dependencies": {
      "body-parser": "~1.0.1",
      "express": "~4.0.0",
      "mongoose": "~3.6.13",
      "nodemon": "^1.9.2",
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "nodemon server.js"
    }
 }
```

I have read that you can import them in the html file, but this is a server with no html, so that is not possible for me.

Comment: `'/router.js'` will search for `router.js` in the root of the filesystem not root of your server, if the file is in the same directory then you need to use `import routers from './router.js';` if it's one directory up in file tree then you to use `'../routers.js'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In router.js file , you can try

```
module.exports = functionYouWantToImport();
```

and in the server.js you can try

```
var routerFunction = require('./router.js');
```

also when you require some local file as a module you should take care the path you are directing

Comment: You don't want to call that function only export it so use `module.exports = functionYouWantToImport;`